# Why did the policeman's brother still have a dorm room after all these years?

Tags: squid-game

In Squid Games, we see the policeman visit his brothers dorm room to find the business card with strange symbols. This leads the policeman to believe that his brother is a participant in the current Squid Games. But in the end we find out that his brother was missing for multiple years, rather than just a couple of weeks as implied by earlier episodes.

So why would the policeman's brother keep a dorm room after all these years? If it was for cover, why did he stop paying for it all of a sudden (the landlord lady mentions she'll clear it out soon for non-payment)?

Comment: No one said that the brother has been missing for multiple years. The games only last about a week, and he left maybe a few weeks earlier to oversee the preparations. He could easily have been living in the outside world before that. And as to why not live in luxury? Winning the games can induce a big shift in one's lifestyle and outlook on life and money. Remember Gi-hun living like a hobo for quite a while?

Comment: @vsz so the brother was living like a slob and then disappeared all of a sudden without paying rent or saying a word?

Comment: I only corrected some false assumptions. I don't know the motivations why he didn't make up a cover story for his family (which would likely have led to them not searching for him, so I don't know why he didn't do it), this is why I only wrote it as a comment, not a full answer.

Comment: Isn't this trivia? Why or how is him having the dorm room relevant?

Comment: @Joachim: The dorm room is the location where the policeman finds a crucial clue to his brother's whereabouts. The question asks how it is supposed to make sense in-universe that this location exists at all, which sounds like a crucial detail of plot logic rather than mere trivia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the second episode, Hwang Jun-ho has a conversation with his mom. He says that he will call everyone who might know where his brother is. He also adds that his brother dodges their calls all the time.  Jun-ho says that if he can't find him by the next day, he will report the brother missing.

Since the brother hasn't been reported missing yet, it's safe to assume he has been missing only for a few days or a few weeks at most and not several years.